# Maximum the result from multiple functions which share an input amount

Tags: algorithms, optimization

[image]

I have multiple functions as shown in the image. For a fixed x value, I need to distribute it into f, g, and h functions for getting the maximum output (y).
In other words, having a fixed x value, find a, b, and c in which these conditions are satisfied:

1. a + b + c = x
2. a >= 0 and b >= 0 and c >= 0
3. f(a) + g(b) + h(c) has max value.
   Given the functions are continuous and monotonic. How should I write code to find out a, b, and c? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Over at [stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74139076)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74139076/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/154805/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Answer (score 1):

As I have not enough reputation yet to comment I just wanted to point out @Yves Daoust's answer is wrong. See my answer on SO for a correct one https://stackoverflow.com/a/74139926/8923995.

Otherwise, here is a counter example to the other answer : [image: example]

Let f be the red function and g the green one. If x is the blue cross, he tells you to answer f(x), the blue point. But if you pick instead f(a)+g(b) where a and b are the purple crosses, you end up with a better result.

Comment: We'd prefer that you not use the 'Your Answer' box to comment on other answers.

Comment: Sure, now that I reached 50 rep I'll be able to comment directly here as well

Answer (score 0):

For a given x, determine the largest among f(x), g(x), h(x), let f(x), and fully utilize this function (a = x, b = c = 0).